# PHP/MySQL - Query database with prepared statement, put each row of data inside individual html element?

Tags: php, html, mysql, prepared-statement

I have 1 PHP file(query), 1 HTML/PHP File(results). I want a prepared statement to query all Data(column1) based on column2 value then put inside a div in another file. I have been trying this for hours and cant seem to get the prepared statement of my own to display the data in the div... Any help would be great, thanks.
Table name: tasks
Column2 = status
Column2 value = o
Column1 = id
PHP file:

```
<?php
include 'sqlconnection.php';
$conn = OpenCon();

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare ( "SELECT id from tasks 
where status=?" ))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param ( "s", $o); 
        $stmt->execute ();
        $stmt->bind_result ($id); 
        $arrayUsers = array();

        while ($stmt->fetch())
        {
            if (isset ($id))
            {
                $arrayUsers[] = array(
                        "id" => $id);
}
}
$stmt->close ();
        }
CloseCon($conn);
?>
```

PHP File with HTML:

```
<div class='task-listing'>
            <h1><?= $id ?></h1>
            <h1><?= $id ?></h1>
            <h1><?= $id ?></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Question, is the php file and the php file with the html in 2 separate files? Unless your storing the array in some fashion you would want to build the html in the same php file with the query. Secondly, when I want to display a php variable in my html I have to put an echo before the variable

Comment: yes, it is 2 separate files

Comment: So if I'm understanding correctly, your php file is querying your database and then storing what you want in $id, but how are you sending the variables to the html side. Have you tried just putting both files together so you dont have to store the variables in a session or local storage?